# Jasper Reporting: How to use JProgressBar to show progress of report compilation?

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

When displaying Jasper Reports in Java code, the report takes some considerable seconds before it is displayed. I would like to use a `JProgressBar` to show the progress of the report and inform the user to wait.  I saw [an example of using progress bar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AdemonstrationoftheJProgressBarcomponent.htm) but I am not able to `stick` it to my code.

Here is my code to generate the report.

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(
    SRTillDate.class.getResourceAsStream("srtdrange.jrxml"));
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, conn);
JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
jv.setTitle("Sales Report");
jv.setVisible(true);
jv.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

**May someone show me how to use a progress bar in this context, shade light into this?**

Comment: Read this https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/504953/progress-monitor

Comment: Look at [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)

Comment: @trashgod Let me look at it